# Beanstalk Cronjobs Stuck Suddenly and not working even a single Cronjob

Tags: laravel, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lumen, kubernetes-cronjob

> I have setup beanstalk cronjobs, I deploy build on this Friday.e 17
> July 2020. So far I judged all cronjobs were working well till
> Saturday i.e 19 July 2020. But from Sunday i.e 20 July 2020, even
> single cronjob is not working.
>
> Then Today I deployed new build and all cronjobs started working fine.
> Can anyone help me to know the reason that why cronjobs were stuck
> suddenly?

```
My Project is Laravel/Lumen and Cronjobs folder name is ".ebextensions" and name of the file(containing cronJobs) is "crontab"
```

> Any help will be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Have you inspected any logs on the EB instance, e.g. `/var/log/cron`? Maybe your cron job crashed?

Comment: can you tell me how to get these logs?

Comment: You can ssh into the EB instance and check `/var/log` or in console in your environment menu there is option called `Logs`

Comment: yeah, there is option for two types of logs 1-100 line 2-full logs which one I should download?
When I download full logs there are too many logs and I'm not able to understand them

Comment: If you allow me I can send you complete logs rar fie in chat?

Comment: Better go though it and if you find something relevant post it. I don't know what kind of application you are running, what cron job does. Only you know that.

Comment: there are notifications type cronjobs that notify user that someone respond your comment aur its time to comment on post etc
I'm checking acccess_log file and before deploying new build I didn't see any of cron job called there but after new cronjob I was there were logs for Cronjobs